# How to apply CORS to a specific rest endpoint

Tags: cors

I am not sure whether I have the right understanding about CORS, but is it possible to apply CORS for a specific rest endpoint under a domain.

Example: Say there two rest endpoints A and B under a domain https://www.example.com/, can I apply CORS only to rest endpoint A.

I think CORS is applied at domain level, but not at endpoint level.

Comment: Yes you can enable CORS access to A without while keeping it disabled for B.

The mechanism for CORS interaction with browsers is just through HTTP headers. So you can choose to return CORS headers in responses to requests to A while also choosing to not return them in responses to requests for B.